# No Column Span property in Pentaho 5.4

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I'm starting with Pentaho 5.4, and as I see in some CDE Dashboard tutorials, column element in Pentaho has a Span property to set the column "weight", but I don't find that property, maybe because it is a diferent version. I see the following column properties:

Name,
Extra Small Devices,
Small Devices,
Large Devices,
Bootstrap Css Class,
Height,
BackgroundColor,
Corners Simple,
Text Align,
Css class

How can i apply that property in Pentaho 5.4? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your dashboard uses Bootstrap and some tutorials refers to Blueprint (see the Settings).
Bootstrap can manage different kinds of devices like tablets,...
If, in first time, you don't really care for that, just use the proeprty "Extra Small Devices".
But be carefull! Blueprint divides your screen in 24 columns ; a contrario, Bootstrap divides it in 12 columns. So, if in a tutorial using Blueprint you see a column with span=12, you must set "Extra Small Devices" to 6

Comment: Thanks a lot, @bhericher